# YUI3 module change attribute after construction

Tags: javascript, module, yui3

I am building a YUI3 module for my workplace. I construct it like so:

```
var testMenu1 = new Y.ContextMenu({
    id: 'testmenu1',
    menuItems: {
        opsdb: {
            title: 'empty',
            type: 'opsdb',
            separator: false,
            action: function(e, host) {
                iframe_panel_opsdb(host);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I'd like to come in later and change the title based on the hostname I right click on. How can I do that given that testMenu1 does now exist. I can do something like testMenu1.set('id', 'newId') but menuItems.opsdb.title, I cannot figure out how to change that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can access nested attributes with dot notation.

Then the following should do what you want, if menuitems is an attributes. (I do not know the details of ContextMenu).

testMenu1.set('menuitems.opsdb.title', 'myNewTitle');

More details there: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/attribute/#subattrs